# Facebook Login Authentication Error With PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I created a Facebook application to login and post to wall using my PHP application.
when I click on login link I am getting error "*Logging in will not add this app's activity to Facebook*" and not prompt the permission request step.

#### EDIT:

I just created a application and when I going to following url it's not prompt "*Request for Permission*".
it's prompt "*Logging in will not add this app's activity to Facebook*" error.

```
https://www.Facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?
  scope=publish_stream,publish_actions,read_stream&
  client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&
  redirect_uri=http://xxxxxx.xxx/post_to_wall.php&
  response_type=token
```

Comment: Plase give more effort while asking a question give your codes and if possible more information about error.

Comment: try with the following example.
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect/

Answer (score 0):

I think Issue is with your URL. refer below URL with is I'm Using and Working absolutely fine.

```
$facebook_link   = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&client_id=".$app_id;
$facebook_link  .= "&redirect_uri=".$url."/settings";
$facebook_link  .= "&scope=publish_stream,offline_access,manage_pages";
```

Try it. may Help you. good luck.

Thanks.

Comment: i checked but still having the same issue